# Asterisk PAMI Originate Outboud Call Issue (PHP)

Tags: php, asterisk, asterisk-java, dahdi

I’m using PAMI to originate a call,
it should make the call from local extension to customer number it works fine but the problem is that
when an I execute the script a call make (from extension to the customer )   when the customer picks this call the problem is: the extension it rings  (incoming call)

it should make automatically (when a customer pick the call the channel should make directly without ringing the extension)

this is my code

```
$originateMsg = new OriginateAction("DAHDI/g1/0603532326");
    $originateMsg->setContext("from-internal");
    $originateMsg->setExtension("4022");
    $originateMsg->setPriority(1);
    $originateMsg->setTimeout(0);
    $originateMsg->setAsync(false);
  var_dump($a->send($originateMsg));
```

Comment: Ok, this is your code. But what is your problem?

Comment: the problem is that when the customer accept  the call the extension 4022 is ringing it should answer directly without return the call   of course and normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options here

1) ring first to extension, not external number

2) send call to queue in which user already waiting for call(called to queue via QueueAgents)

3) ring first to conference. Create the second call to conference and to extension.

Third variant requires manage of events and complex dialplan. Seams like you have only options 1,2 at your experience level.